# Change scroll distance covered with one tick of the scrollwhell

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, distance

I am searching for a solution to get this effect:
http://www.socketstudios.com

So you scroll not only 1 or 2 px, but 1080 or even better 100%.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: it uses jquery [`mouseweel`](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) and [`scrollTo`](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugins, you can read their documentations.

Comment: It appears to me he's capturing the `scroll` event and using it to trigger a `hashchange` instead. Then the images are scrolling rapidly up or down to make it look like the user is scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Your example site isn't doing what you're asking for.

In the example, they're using JavaScript to animate the images scrolling out of view so it looks like they're flying off into the far distance. View it with JavaScript disabled and you'll see there's not actually a big page to scroll through (it's rather empty in fact).

To do what you're actually asking is a Windows setting available in the Control Panel:

[image: Mouse settings]

Comment: and how do i get this effect? is he using a slider or what?